# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Guid' in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am getting **"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Guid'"** Error which is mentioned in the below image. I searched many solutions for this error but i cant able to clear this error.
[image]

The UserID is Guid in both User and UserRights Table which is mentioned in the below image.

[image]

**My Code**

```
 public class Config
{
    public static class Forms
    {

        public static readonly Guid UserScreen = new Guid("803F9EDF-71A6-4B47-8583-6FE50ED0BC06");
        public static readonly Guid VisitorsForm = new Guid("3C93D64F-802B-4F4B-8564-6115AE73F354");
    }
    public static Guid UserID { get { return GetUserID(); } }
   private static Guid GetUserID()
    {
        string user = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
        return new Guid(user);
    }
    public static WafeERPEntities GetDb()
    {
        return new WafeERPEntities();
    }
    public static List<UserRight> GetFormRights()
    {
        return GetDb().UserRights.Where(u => u.UserID == Config.UserID).ToList();
    }
    public static UserRight GetFormRights(Guid formID)
    {
        return GetDb().UserRights.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserScreenID == formID && u.UserID == Config.UserID);
    }
}
}
```

Any one help me to resolve this issue.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason for it to work if you compare Guid with String, you can only compare correct types using `==` operator, not anything to anything. Also post the code snippet with an issue, not complete image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of this solutions

1) You can use *ToString()* as fast solution. This method is better from performance pointofview :

```
  (u=>string.Equals(u.UsserId.Tostring()),Config.Userid, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

2) You can parse Guid as another fast solution. This methods is not so good for performance as previous, but in the case of incorrect guid you will be informed about it with help of exception:

```
u=>
{
    var parsedGuid;
    return Guid.Parse(Config.Userid)==Config.Userid;
}
```

to avoid exceptions you can use:

```
u=>
{
    var parsedGuid;
    if(Guid.TryParse(Config.Userid,out parsedGuid))
        return parsedGuid u.UsserId.Tostring()==Config.Userid;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

3) Correct way. you should change your DB model to keep userId not in *string* but in *Guid*. In other words `UserRight.UsserId` should have type *Guid*

Comment: Add `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `string comparison`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thanks. already done

Comment: @MichalHainc this is good example for "stringly-typed code" - https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/

Comment: @Michal Hainc most of providers are `Ok` for default conversion between `Guid` and `String`, especially if its an auto generated code. Here wrong usage `==` is an issue, which needs to be corrected

Comment: @MichalHainc for applications where processing time is important, may be it will be better to not use Parse method, since it  can lead to slow down on big set of data;

Comment: @MichalHainc guys, in general, i agree with you, and have the same opinion

Comment: Why giving negative marks to my question if i did any mistake in that question means tell me how to ask or edit my question . See now my account got blocked . Now i cant ask question from my account. How can i ask my doubt in future. Without knowing another person reason you peoples give negative marks easily

Comment: @MichalHainc see now my account got blocked :( how i ask my doubts in future :( :(

Comment: @MichalHainc help me to recover my account

Comment: @Susan i didn't minus your question too. But in general voting down question means: "This question doesn't show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: @burzhuy yes i understand now help me to recover my account. Tell me how to edit m question :(

Comment: @MichalHainc you can able to give postive marks right atleast give that itself so i can gain my account again and if it possible means edit my question in corret way

Comment: @MichalHainc is it possible to edit my question in right way so that some peoples can give postive marks. i am not that much good in communication skills

Comment: @Susan did you try to search ? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261846/why-my-account-has-been-blocked-for-asking-questions-that-are-very-valuable-to-a

Comment: @burzhuy what you want me to search . tell  that i will do

Comment: @burzhuy did you saw in that question the person who asked how to recover my account question that person also got negative marks alot

Comment: @burzhuy i searched in this forum to recover my account . they said improve your past question and geting postive points to that question which you got negative marks means your account will recover automatically